# Java / Android - Efficient custom search suggestions via network

Tags: java, android, multithreading, search

This may be a little strange (which is why I'm checking on Stack Overflow) but what I'm doing is writing an Android app with a search widget, which is returning custom results in a search suggestion popup (as in screen shot below).

The twist being I'm returning the search suggestions from a web API.

[image: Custom results in a search suggestion popup]

I've created a custom content provider which does the following in the query() method, and it works fine though my problem is, is that the query() method is called after each letter is entered into the search input field - which means that if I type in a search term (for example) which is 10 letters long, it'll send 10 search queries to the web API.

```
public Cursor query(final Uri uri,
                    final String[] projection,
                    final String selection,
                    final String[] selectionArgs,
                    final String sortOrder) {

    // Query the web API here

    final MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor( /* populate with columns */ );

    // Add results from web API to cursor

    return cursor;
}
```

To get around this on the iOS version of the app, I set a timer which executes after 0.7 seconds and then performs the web API call.  This timer gets reset after each key press so the user has to essentially pause their typing a bit before the results are displayed.

I can do this on iOS, as the search results can be returned asynchronously though on Android, the query() method needs to return the result synchronously.

Is there a way to do something similar on Android where I can set a timer, or am I going about this the wrong way for custom search suggestions?

Comment: are you using android.widget.SearchView?

Comment: @pskink Kind of, I'm actually using the SearchView from the support library (android.support.v7.widget.SearchView) but I think they're equivalent.  Why is that?

Comment: have no experience with SV so i dont know how to "control" query operations, sorry

Comment: did you solve this somehow please?

Comment: Hi @marson, sorry I didn't solve this in the end.  The client was more than happy with the performance of the app in the current state so I didn't get any more time to work on it